# My windows server is flooded with event id 5447!

Tags: windows

I don't have any idea whats causing this event. Every two minutes I am getting 100 of these logs and its consuming my bandwidth.

> MSWinEventLog:             WindowsServer2012R2Standard               0
>   Security                2686990                Wed Mar 16 23:48:24 EDT
>   2016            5447       Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
>   Unknown            Unknown            Information
>
> ######                Other Policy Change Events        Info        Audit Success    A Windows Filtering Platform filter has been changed.
>
> Subject: Security ID: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE Account Name: NT
>   AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE Process Information: Process ID: 1120 Provider
>   Information: ID: {DECC16CA-3F33-4346-BE1E-8FB4AE0F3D62} Name:
>   Microsoft Corporation Change Information: Change Type: Delete
>
> Filter Information: ID: {D579C047-5927-49E6-BF80-FC8DC1C61275} Name:
>   Connection Broker Service (RPC-EPMAP) Type: Not persistent Run-Time
>   ID: 294386 Layer Information: ID:
>   {A3B42C97-9F04-4672-B87E-CEE9C483257F} Name: ALE Receive/Accept v6
>   Layer Run-Time ID: 46 Callout Information: ID:
>   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Name: - Additional Information:
>   Weight: 10376540038224674816 Conditions: Condition ID:
>   {d78e1e87-8644-4ea5-9437-d809ecefc971} Match value: Equal to Condition
>   value: 00000000 5c 00 64 00 65 00 76 00-69 00 63 00 65 00 5c 00
>   .d.e.v.i.c.e.. 00000010 68 00 61 00 72 00 64 00-64 00 69 00 73 00 6b
>   00 h.a.r.d.d.i.s.k. 00000020 76 00 6f 00 6c 00 75 00-6d 00 65 00 32 00
>   5c 00 v.o.l.u.m.e.2.. 00000030 77 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00-6f 00 77 00 73
>   00 5c 00 w.i.n.d.o.w.s.. 00000040 73 00 79 00 73 00 74 00-65 00 6d 00
>   33 00 32 00 s.y.s.t.e.m.3.2. 00000050 5c 00 74 00 73 00 73 00-64 00 69
>   00 73 00 2e 00 .t.s.s.d.i.s... 00000060 65 00 78 00 65 00 00 00
>   e.x.e... Condition ID: {af043a0a-b34d-4f86-979c-c90371af6e66} Match
>   value: Equal to Condition value:
>   O:SYG:SYD:(A;;CCRC;;;S-1-5-80-979556362-403687129-3954533659-2335141334-1547273080)
>   Condition ID: {0c1ba1af-5765-453f-af22-a8f791ac775b} Match value:
>   Equal to Condition value: 0x0251 Condition ID:
>   {3971ef2b-623e-4f9a-8cb1-6e79b806b9a7} Match value: Equal to Condition
>   value: 0x06 Filter Action: Permit 66957945

1) What is causing these log messages?

2) How do I prevent them from consuming bandwidth?

Last but not least, what does the number "2686990" mean in

> MSWinEventLog: WindowsServer2012R2Standard 0 Security 2686990 Wed Mar 16 23:48:24 EDT 2016 5447 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

Comment: Can you Check which process is running on Process ID: 1120 from task manager?

Comment: @saravan i cant see any process id 1120 on task manager. checked it but unable to find it

Comment: Try Clicking `Show Process from all users` button  which requires admin privileges

Comment: Just checked it out again and could see MPSSVC, DPS,BFE process running under 1120

Comment: -1 due to obvious lack of thought. No bandwidth is used, the number is no flooding and formatting is not optional.

Answer (score 2):

What bandwidth are you referring to? Event logs do not consume bandwidth, and 100 every 2 minutes is not what I would call "flooded"<sup>1</sup>.

With your event log pasted blindly into the question the way it has been, makes it impossible to actually read. Try posting it again, but this time as `code` formatted, and it should maintain some semblance of readability.

The first thing you need to do is found out which process has PID `1120`. This will tell you what is generating these events. Based on your comments, it appears that this might be [`MPSSVC`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715818.aspx), which is the Windows Firewall.

Secondly we know it's doing some sort of `delete` operation, triggered by a rule or filter for `RPC-EPMAP` (which appears to be part of the Windows RPC framework).

That's really all I can gleam from what you have posted there, as unfortunately, although I am very good at interpreting large blobs of unformatted text, this one evades my attempts.

<sub><sup>1</sup>For what it's worth, I just had a single event log receive 60,000 events in under 60 seconds. *That* I consider flooded.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

These are firewall log entries, if you are sure this is not an ongoing attack, try to disable the Firewall Option: "Other Policy Change Events".

5447 - A Windows Filtering Platform filter has been changed.
TechNet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/dd772640(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: how can i make sure if this is not an attack